iOS 18.0 Shared Extention Open App URL Can't Work
iOS 18.0 Shared Extention Open App URL Can't Work
Xcode 16
Swift 5.9
private func openMainApp() {
    let urlScheme = "AppName://"
    if let url = URL(string: urlScheme) {
        
        if self.openURL(url) {
            print( "RUN : APP")
        } else {
            print( "NOT RUN : APP")
        }
        close()
    }
}

@objc private func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}

I also put my app name in AppName and confirmed that it worked normally in iOS 17 version, but it's not working in 18.
I thought the name of the app was different
I changed my name
I've checked it through simulation of other app versions, but it only happens with iOS 18.
Also, when you build it with a real device, it still doesn't work.

The code that you posted tries to use an implementation to call openURL(:), which is deprecated and causes problems on iOS 18. So you need to replace the use of #selector(openURL(:)) with the use of the correct method UIApplication.shared.open(_:options:completionHandler:).
 @discardableResult
    @objc func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                application.open(url, options: [:]) { success in
                    if success {
                        print("App opened successfully")
                    } else {
                        print("Failed to open app")
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
            responder = responder?.next
        }
        return false
    }


It would be useful if you could explain the code, too, so that people can understand what they have done wrong.

Yep, you are right.The code that the guy posted tries to use an implementation to call openURL(:), which is deprecated and causes problems on iOS 18. So you need to replace the use of #selector(openURL(:)) with the use of the correct method UIApplication.shared.open(_:options:completionHandler:).

That's great, thanks. Could you edit your answer to include that description, so it's easy for people to see without having to read the comments? Thanks.

That's great, thanks.

Thank you so much yama, You made my day. Hope this won't disturb app store review +1

Objective-C version:
UIResponder* responder = self;
while (responder)
{
    if ([responder respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)] && [responder isMemberOfClass:[UIApplication class]])
    {
        [((UIApplication *)responder) openURL:yourURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    }
    responder = [responder nextResponder];
}

